# Can't iterate to multiple list while using enumerate in python

Tags: python

I wanted to print each value in the list below. I also need to know the index. so I wanted to use enumarate:

```
a = [(10, 0, 3), (10, 10, 6), (10, 15, 4), (10, 20, 5), (10, 3, 3),
         (10, 5, 6), (10, 0, 3), (10, 10, 3), (10, 40, 6), (10, 45, 5), (10, 50, 6)]

for i, measurment in enumerate(a):
        for a,b,c in measurment:
            print( a,b,c)
```

But unfortunately i am having this error: 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: `for i,t in enumerate(a): print(i,*t) `

Answer (score 4):

No need for the nested loop, you can unpack directly:

```
a = [(10, 0, 3), (10, 10, 6), (10, 15, 4), (10, 20, 5), (10, 3, 3),
         (10, 5, 6), (10, 0, 3), (10, 10, 3), (10, 40, 6), (10, 45, 5), (10, 50, 6)]

for i, (a, b, c) in enumerate(a):
    print(i, a, b, c)
```

**Output**

```
0 10 0 3
1 10 10 6
2 10 15 4
3 10 20 5
4 10 3 3
5 10 5 6
6 10 0 3
7 10 10 3
8 10 40 6
9 10 45 5
10 10 50 6
```

Comment: thank you. but what's wrong with my code? why it's not working? measurement is a tuple. I should loop through it?

Comment: When you loop through the tuple, it gives you an integer each time through the loop. Unless you wanted the loop to print each measurement independently, it won't work.

Comment: @Kazi: `for a, b, c in measurement` will loop over each value in the tuple, and then attempt to unpack that value into a tuple of three values to assign to `a`, `b`, and `c` respectively. `for a, b, c in measurement` is equivalent to: `for item in measurement: a, b, c = item` which is why it gives you the error that the item cannot be iterated.

Comment: Yes you can iterate over it, but one element at the time, your loop assumes measurement  is a an iterable composed of three elements each